# How to extract rows from a QueryResult array from Postgres

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql

I am getting my DB response as an array which is the result of running two queries. I need to extract the rows present in the Result.
How can I extract the rows which are having the Objects?

Or any other way to get the data correctly? Please note that I ran two queries simultaneously and that's why getting such a response.

I am not pasting any tried code here so please forgive me for that.

```
[ Result {
command: 'SELECT',
rowCount: 7,
oid: null,
rows:
 [ [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object] ],
fields: [ [Field], [Field], [Field] ],
_parsers:
 [ [Function: parseBigInteger],
   [Function: noParse],
   [Function: noParse] ],
_types: TypeOverrides { _types: [Object], text: {}, binary: {} },
RowCtor: null,
rowAsArray: false },
Result {
command: 'SELECT',
rowCount: 11,
oid: null,
rows:
 [ [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object],
   [Object] ],
fields: [ [Field], [Field], [Field] ],
_parsers:
 [ [Function: parseBigInteger],
   [Function: noParse],
   [Function: noParse] ],
_types: undefined,
RowCtor: null,
rowAsArray: false } ]
```

JSON.stringify(dbres, null, 4) gives me

```
[
{
    "command": "SELECT",
    "rowCount": 7,
    "oid": null,
    "rows": [
        {
            "count": "11",
            "a_id": "solution",
            "a_description": "Solution"
      }]
}]
```

Comment: what are inside rows ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee the row data, as Objects.

Comment: Its unclear what is inside it, without knowing I cant help. Maybe you can do a `JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)` and post the contents and update the question. Maybe we can help from there

Comment: @KunalMukherjee updated the question.

Comment: `result.rows` should give you what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to go through the results of your queries and then for each query, map through the rows.
the following should do more or less the trick

```
interface IQResult {
    queryId: number;
    queryResults: Array<Record<string, any>>;
}

    const t =
        dbres &&
        dbres.map((res, index) => {
            let qResult: IQResult = {
                queryId: index,
                queryResults: [],
            };

            res &&
                res.forEach(
                    (r) =>
                        (qResult = {
                            ...qResult,
                            queryResults: [...qResult.queryResults, ...r.rows],
                        })
                );
        });
```